# Why Clang gives error no member named 'copy' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I am trying to make some basic compilations in clang and I am getting the following error for copy function (which my understanding is that it shall be under std namespace).

This is my complete replicable code:

**Triangle.h**

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H

class Triangle {

    public:

        Triangle();
        ~Triangle();

        void DefineTriangleVertices(float vertex[6]);

    private:

        float m_vertex[6];

};

#endif /* TRIANGLE_H */
```

**Triangle.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Triangle.h"

Triangle::Triangle() {
}

void Triangle::DefineTriangleVertices(float data[]) {
    std::copy(data,6,m_vertex);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum glewReturn = glewInit();
    if(glewReturn != GLEW_OK) {
        cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(glewReturn) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(+0.5f, -0.5f);
        glEnd();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
clang++    -c -g -I/usr/local/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/CLang-Generic/Triangle.o.d" -o build/Debug/CLang-Generic/Triangle.o Triangle.cpp
Triangle.cpp:21:10: error: no member named 'copy' in namespace 'std'
    std::copy(data,6,m_vertex);
    ~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Namespaces != Headers. You need to `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Missing `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Thanks, I thought copy definition was part of `cstdlib` header.

Comment: The top of each page on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) tells you which header needs to be included. [cstdlib](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) only contains a few c functions

Comment: Thanks, I am a newcomer to C++  from C89

Answer (score 1):

Following question's comments:

```
#include <algorithm>

#include "Triangle.h"

Triangle::Triangle() {
}

void Triangle::DefineTriangleVertices(float data[]) {
    std::copy(data,data+6,m_vertex);
}
```